# Add data to abstract table Java spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, abstracttablemodel

I have two entities generate by hibernate (in postgres)

here is my MCD (many to many - User bottle) :[image]
All work fine, but my abstract table is not completed.

Screen from my table User_Bottle :

[image]

i would like to add this data to my table, but i don't know how to do, here is my service (i'm beginner in spring):

```
    public void addBottleToUser(UserBottleDTO userBottleDto) {

    //Variable that i would like to add into my request
    String userEmail;
    Long bottleIdl;
    String scorel;
    String opinion;
    String with;
    String place;
    String date;

    User userDb = this.userDao.findByEmail(userBottleDto.getUserEmail());
    Bottle bottleDb = this.bottleDao.findById(userBottleDto.getBottleId());
    Set<Bottle> bottles = new HashSet<Bottle>();
    bottles = userDb.getBottles();
    bottles.add(bottleDb);
    userDb.setBottles(bottles);

    this.userDao.save(userDb);
}
```

user class (entity): 
https://pastebin.com/KAuyvBAJ

bottle class (entity):
https://pastebin.com/NmrqpVEQ

i can print my DAO, DTO if you want, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If relation doesn't be annotated with @ManyToMany; you need to save your abstract table record same as bottle or user.

Comment: this is not answer ,you should add it into comment

Comment: I dont have enough reputation point to comment. Sorry; i just try to help.

Comment: I added user and bottle class